# Google Analytics stop tracking view

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to start using GA SDK v2 for Android for "page views"/activity visit tracking. Recommended procedure is to use EasyTracker with calling activityStart()/activityStop() in onStart/onStop methods. Problem is that I need to create page names dynamically (during onCreate) so I can't use XML mapping to activity names in analytics.xml.
So I'm using EasyTracker.getTracker().sendView() method in onStart() in my Activity. If I understand it correctly this should be some sort of replacement of activityStart(). Question is - is there any replacement for activityStop()? Some sort of stopTrackingView()? Because of Android activity lifecycle there should be some sort of this method to make metrics more precise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use xml in your app.

[Use this way](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced) to track Views and Events in your app

Comment: I'm currently using sendView method if you want to point to that method. Question is different and is based on activity lifecycle - see original question.